# Phrase corresponding to "Welcome to X" that is used when leaving?

Tags: phrase-requests

For written text on signboards, what is a phrase corresponding to "Welcome to Central City" that is used when leaving? Is there a phrase of the form "[insert word] from Central City"?

I thought of using "Bon voyage", which has the exact meaning that I want. However, I need a phrase that contains the name of the location. I then thought about using "You are leaving Central City", but this lacks the well-wishing and fanfare that "Welcome to Central City" contains. At the end, I came up with "Bon voyage. You are leaving Central City". Is there a better phrase?

Comment: Y'all come back now, ya hear?

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of "Thanks for visiting Central City. Come back soon."

Answer (score 2):

Usually I think of the phrase corresponding to “Welcome to -x-” as “Thank you for -related verb- -x-”

“Thank you for visiting Central City.”
“Thank you for shopping at shoppingcenter.”
“Thank you for flying (on) air planecompany.”

Comment: You see "Thank you for visiting Central City" or sometimes "You are now leaving Central City" road signs.

Answer (score 0):

*Goodbye from Central City?*

The Scottish side of the border with England has "Haste Ye Back"